# Test view C# simulate user action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am doing a project in MVC 3 with C# and would like to put test cases to simulate user actions in Views, and compare if the data was saved correctly in the database. But searched and did not find any material or good example.

Any suggestions how to do?

Comment: The problem was he did not know how to implement end-to-end test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "end-to-end" testing, or "integration" testing, and there are many frameworks and solutions out there for this.

One that I have used in the past is Selenium: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

But there are many others: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools

They are called "end-to-end" because they automate the UI as if it is the user performing the actions, and then they run steps to validate the results of said actions; in this way, they test the entire application at once rather than each independent component individually (as is the case with Unit Tests).

Answer (score 0):

An important aspect of writing tests is that views and UI are difficult to test / simulate.  MVC and MVVM get around this by letting you test your Model and Controller or your Model and ViewModel.

There are tools that help you to test the views for doing UI testing like Watin, Selenium etc.